# Replace Union All with joins or recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, union-all

Table A

| ID | Employee Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ashley |
| 2 | Sam |
| 3 | Samantha |
| 4 | Jessica |
| 5 | Tom |

Table B

| ID | Week | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | week 1 | 100 |
| 2 | week 1 | 50 |
| 3 | week 1 | 100 |
| 4 | week 1 | 50 |
| 1 | week 2 | 100 |
| 2 | week 2 | 50 |
| 5 | week 2 | 100 |
| 2 | week 3 | 20 |
| 3 | week 3 | 100 |
| 4 | week 3 | 50 |
| 5 | week 3 | 100 |

I want output as:

Table C

| ID | This Week | This week Salary | Next Week | Next week Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | week 1 | 100 | week 2 | 100 |
| 2 | week 1 | 50 | week 2 | 50 |
| 3 | week 1 | 100 | Null |  |
| 4 | week 1 | 50 | Null |  |
| 5 | Null |  | week 2 | 100 |
| 1 | week 2 | 100 | Null |  |
| 2 | week 2 | 50 | Week 3 | 20 |
| 3 | Null |  | Week 3 | 100 |
| 4 | Null |  | Week 3 | 50 |
| 5 | Null |  | Week 3 | 100 |
| 1 | NULL |  | Week 4 | 20 |
| 2 | Week 3 | 20 | Week 4 | 80 |
| 3 | Week 3 | 100 | Null |  |
| 4 | Week 3 | 50 | Null |  |
| 5 | Week 3 | 100 | Null |  |

I have 14 weeks of data.
In order to join 14 weeks of data I might need to do 14 union all. I am looking for an alternative to that

My attempt:

```
Select A.*, B.* from Table A
Left Outer join Table B      on A.Id = B.ID and B.week = Week 1
Left Outer join Table B AS C on A.Id = C.ID and C.week = Week 2
UNION ALL
Select * from Table A
Left Outer join Table B on A.Id = B.ID and week = Week 2
Left Outer join Table B AS C on A.Id = C.ID and C.week = Week 3
```

Comment: What are you asking here? Is your attempt not working? Is it not performing as you want? Something else? The problem looks like you've simply omitted the single quotes (`'`) around your literal strings.

Comment: In order to join 14 weeks of data I might need to do 14 union all. I am looking for an alternative to that

Comment: Please undo the efforts of others who take the time to improve the formatted of your posts as well.

Comment: So [edit] your question to clarify the problem and what your question is. When posting a question it's important to *ask* a *question*.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new set of columns for each week found in your data? You would have to use dynamic sql for that. Most likely either `dynamic cross tab` or a `dynamic pivot`. Either of those search options will reveal dozens and dozens of nearly identical questions with answers. Or maybe you just need to look at `LEAD/LAG` window functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for a recursive CTE here, you can just make a dataset of your distinct weeks and employees. Ideally you should have a separate table for your weeks (if you don't I recommend doing so), but you can use a `DISTINCT` if not. I also *assume* your week column is really an `int`, not a `varchar`. If it isn't fix that design; week 2 is meant to be *before* week 10, but with a `varchar` it would be *after*, and your design is flawed.

With all that, this gives a solution like thebelow:

```sql
WITH EmployeeWeeks AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           E.EmployeeID,
           S.Week
    FROM dbo.Employee E
         CROSS JOIN dbo.Salary S)
SELECT EW.EmployeeID,
       S.Week,
       S.Salary,
       LEAD(S.Week) OVER (PARTITION BY EW.EmployeeID ORDER BY EW.Week) AS NextWeek,
       LEAD(S.Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY EW.EmployeeID ORDER BY EW.Week) AS NextSalary
FROM EmployeeWeeks EW
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Salary S ON EW.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID
                           AND EW.Week = S.Week
ORDER BY EW.[Week],
         EW.EmployeeID;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jzb5epRJ)
<sub>Note, that the sample data given by the OP has no data for week 4, so does not give the expected results in the fiddle, as it's impossible to give data for sample data we're missing.</sub>

Answer (score -3):

you can use JOINS to generate the weeks and then perform LEFT JOIN for table B for each week.